# Optimization problem with black box constraint

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I have the objective function

$$f(x,y,z)=(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2$$

which measures the squared distance between two bodies, $A$ (fixed) and $B$ (movable). The center of gravity of $A$ is $(a,b,c)$ and the center of gravity of $B$ is $(x,y,z)$. As said, only body $B$ is movable while $A$ is fixed in space.

My constraint, for now, is a function $g$ that gives the intersecting volume  which should be $0$. Function $g$ takes $6$ input parameters $(x,y,z,\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ where the angles are the rotation of movable body $B$. The problems with the constraint function $g$ are as follows.

1. It is not differentiable at the point where the constraint is satisfied (where the intersecting volume is $0$).
2. It is a black box. I do not know how to get that function analytically. I just give it values and it automatically calculates the intersecting volume.

I have two questions for the same:

1. Are gradient-based algorithms still valid given constraint is not differentiable at some point and is a black box? I would be grateful if you could provide me any reasoning or any hint with your answer.
2. Any particular algorithm which is suitable for problem of these type ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks for the edit!!!

Comment: You are welcome.