# Converting Non-Differentiable function to Differentiable Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

this post specifically regarding my previous problem stated here
[Optimization problem with black box constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198208/optimization-problem-with-black-box-constraint)

But I think it could be a general problem also. Assume a nonlinear function $g$ such that $g\ge 0$ and is nonsmooth (not differentiable) at $g=0$.

My aim is to find a function $f$ such that $f(g)$ is always smooth.

For example if I take the function $g=|x|$ and then take $f=x^n$ where $n>2$ makes it smooth.

I took one more example as below, as
$g={x^2 +x^{0.5}+x^{3.5};x\ge 0}$ otherwise $g=0;x<0$ and taking $f$ as above, made it smooth (at least seeing graphically).

Is my approach correct to make non-smooth functions, smooth? Would appreciate any help on the same.

Comment: Can I just choose $f = 0$?

Comment: The thing is I need to calculate the gradient of the function g for some optimization process and g function is nondifferentiable at g=0. Therefore taking f=0, would just make g lose all its properties required for optimization.